# Pandas ,after converting into date time, not sorting properly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I read in a csv file, the column in question looks like this :

```
0         1927-08-16
15        1953-01-01
16        1966-11-28
17        1950-10-18
```

I drop all blank values:

```
cash['DATE'].replace('',np.nan, inplace=True)
cash.dropna(subset=['DATE'],inplace=True)
```

Now I want to convert :

```
cash['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(cash['DATE'],errors='ignore')
```

All that is left is to sort:

```
cash.sort_values(by=['DATE'], ascending=False)
```

Now I check :

```
cash['DATE='].tail(6)
```

Unfortunately the output is :

```
329412    1999-03-01
329413    2012-12-13
329414    2014-01-03
329415    2014-01-03
329416    2007-06-30
329417    1991-12-31
```

Clearly not sorted properly. Any Idea where I went wrong. Any tip or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with `errors='coerce'`

Comment: Same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the value of the dataframe, you need

```
cash = cash.sort_values(by=['DATE'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: or alternatively, pass `inplace=True` as they did for earlier commands